# Commands not being recognized by discord.py

Tags: python, discord

I have a simple discord.py set up trying to use .ping, but in this current instance, the actual sending of ".ping" results in nothing being sent by the bot. Is there something I'm missing here?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Everything's all ready to go~")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    author = message.author
    content = message.content
    print(content)

@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    author = message.author
    channel = message.channel
    await bot.send_message(channel, message.content)

@bot.command()
async def ping():
    await bot.say('Pong!')

bot.run('Token')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have `await bot.process_commands(message)` somewhere in your `on_message` event.

> **Why does *on_message* make my commands stop working?**
>
> Overriding the default provided on_message forbids any extra commands from running. To fix this, add a `bot.process_commands(message)` line at the end of your `on_message`. For example:
>
> ```py
> @bot.event
> async def on_message(message):
>    # do some extra stuff here
>
>     await bot.process_commands(message)
> ```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working